# log4j prints debug to file, but not info

Tags: java, xml, log4j

I am able to print debug logs to a file, but I am unable to print info. However, printing info and debug to console works correctly. How do I go about getting info to print in a file as well?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value= "%-5p [%t]: %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <appender name="R" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="file" value="example.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1000000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value= "%-5p [%t]: %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value="info" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="stdout" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="R" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was using the java logger object rather than the apache4j logger object...